# How to terminate all activities in the stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the following activity stack in my application:
Activity A -> Activity B

Normally if the application is showing activity B, pressing the back button would return to A. This is fine. Now I have a button in activity B that basically terminates the entire application because I want the user to be able to terminate the app at any give activity. When I press the button, I want the app to terminate all activities and return to the home screen.

However, since I have activities in the stack, calling finish() in activity B will simply return to A. How should I implement it so that activity A will also be destroyed? I still want to retain activity A in the stack if creating the activity B from A.

Here's my code, but I don't think it's going to help much:

button in Activity A

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setText("Start ActB");
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

button in Activity B

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setText("Finish");
    b.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to work around it: using `startActivityForResult()`, `setResult()`, and `onActivityResult` together.

Here's what I have:

ActivityA:

```java
public static final int RESULT_CODE_FINISH = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setText("Start ActB");
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
    switch (resultCode) {
        case RESULT_CODE_FINISH:
            this.finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

ActivityB:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setText("Finish");
    b.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setResult(ActivityA.RESULT_CODE_FINISH);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For clearing all the activities on top of ActivityA you should do something like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

For restarting your app you should do something like this:

```
Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

For closing the app on button in ActivityB you should use this:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Did you replace in B Activity the finish() method  for the code above?

Comment: Why do I need to start activity A in activity B?

Comment: Ok, so you want to close the app in that button in activity B that now is using method finish? You should use there System.exit(0);

Comment: System.exit(0); gives me the same result: it's still returning to activity A.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the activity launchMode and clearTaskOnLaunch flags

For reference : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html